# work with two container view using segmented controller

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

M learn Container View using objective c.

Here, try to display two container one by one using segmented Controller.
Two container use container name is containerViewA, containerViewB.
I am running the app that time only containerViewB is load.

Code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewA;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewB;
@end

- (IBAction)ShowComponent:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.5) animations:^{
            self.containerViewA.alpha = 1;
            self.containerViewB.alpha = 0;
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.5) animations:^{
            self.containerViewA.alpha = 0;
            self.containerViewB.alpha = 1;
        }];
    }
}
```

Update:

[image]

Update 1:

Storyboard side panel.

[image]

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: first container is not display.@Akhilrajtr

Comment: Please try printing the value of sender.selectedSegmentIndex before if and tell what it is?

Comment: Hey, when click on first container it return first otherwise 0. but click on first or second it load only second container. @user1000

Comment: When you click on First Segment it prints 0 and When you click on Second Segment it prints 1, right?

Comment: yes right.@user1000

Comment: Put a debug breakpoint on both if and else part see which runs when?

Comment: when value 1 execute else part and value 0 execute if part. @user1000

Comment: please again fast go through the tutorial again, I think problem is with the values of constraints set in the stroyboard

Comment: Please show the storyboard side panel, where view hierarchy is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewA;` and `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewB;` are connected properly.

Comment: make sure `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewA;` and `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewB;` are connected. all other seems correct.

Comment: means you say both container is container is connected with each other?

Comment: @GanganiRoshan No I think he means that connection to the views in storyboard and these outlets should be established